# Azure metrics returning 0s from MetricsClient

Tags: c#, azure, metrics, azure-management-api

I have a nightly job that gathers a couple of different metrics from Azure, using the the MetricsClient from Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.  This has been set up and was working for a while.  However recently it stopped working properly.

I get a successful response back, but the Total and Average properties are being set to 0.  The Count has a value and the Max has a value, so there should definitely be a Total and Average.  And when I log into the portal, there are values in the Average Response Time chart.

This seems like an Azure metrics issue.  Is anyone else seeing this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the latest metrics REST API in Azure Monitor?

Here are a few references:

REST API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics

Supported metrics
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics

Sample C# for retrieving metrics
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/monitor-dotnet-metrics-api/